# Search MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, search

I have the below Code

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(message) AGAINST ('Hello*')
```

If the message string is like this

```
"HelloWhatsHappening"
```

It dosent Work return anything

But if i have

```
"Hello WhatsHappening"
```

It works fine

It will also work if the string is as such:

```
"Hello= WhatsHappening"
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Should i be using a Like Query by splitting all the words above into an array of words to search from. But then how do you match the ones that apear the most?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify your query with a wild card, and add the "IN BOOLEAN MODE" statement.  Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(message) AGAINST ('Hello*'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

You also might have troubles searching for hello, because it is one of the [stop words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) in MySQL.  So it doesn't index the word if it is just hello, but it will index it if it's the word "HelloWhatsHappening".

Comment: ooo im sorry.. i forgot that in the question.. Its Already doing That :(

Comment: Wait i think ima twonk :D... in my table the Hello is stored as such "Hello:" but is there a reason why that dont work

Comment: It will interpret Hello: as Hello, because the : is not a word character.  As such, it will not Index Hello: as it is a stop word.